# file upload string or binary data would be truncated

Tags: asp.net

Hi Guys I have been struggling with this issue for days now. I have a website that uploads different file types, creates thumbs from the files and saves the file and thumbs to their respective folders. every so often it throws an exception  string or binary data would be truncated, Ive never encountered this locally. I have a problem pinning down  the circumstances that it happens, I thought it was documents with spaces in the name but that works sometimes as well. This is really bugging me and I need to fix this. The db table fields are long enough, trust me . Has anyone else ever encountered this issue?

Comment: Do you save files in DB or locally ?

Comment: The thing is it works for me normally, then after tests, a tester reports the bug, the tester uses mac/safari, I have also tested this myself and it works

Comment: But it also seems to break randomly sometimes which makes no sense

Comment: That error message typically comes from the database, not the file system.  Have you been able to reproduce it?  If so, I would double-check the data being saved to the database and make sure it doesn't exceed your column sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I know all this, this is  a db error etc, but the fields are long enough. I have not been able to reproduce this, my log files are empty. This is very weird